# moving raid 10 to another identical server both on Smart Array 6i controllers

Tags: raid, hardware, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

I have dead HP DL 380G4 with RAID 1+0 with 1 logical volume from 4x72GB drives on built-in Smart Array 6i 128Mb BBWC. It was shut down properly. It seems it was usual death for Proliant with ILO led 2,3,8 lighting.  I want to move array to another identical server with same raid firmware level.

What is the best strategy?:
I have RAID 1+0 on 
bay 0
bay 1
bay 2
bay 3

As I understand bay0+bay1 are in RAID 1 , bay2+bay3 are in RAID 1, and both RAID 1 pairs are in RAID 0.

So should I :

Clear RAID config on new server, insert bay 0, bay 2 and power-on

or

Create RAID 1+0 with 1 logical volume from clear HDDs , and then poweroff ,remove HDDs and insert 2 HDDs(bay 0, bay 2) from old RAID 1+0. then power-on. (each hdd has its raid position info stored but may be could work on same config)

According to documentation for Smart Array 6i it could be possible to migrate. however one requirement point is unclear for me

> ```
> Before you move drives, the following conditions must be met: 
> •  The array is in its original configuration. "
> ```

What is orginal and non-original config for RAID 1+0?

Another point

> "If you want to move an array to another controller, you must also
>   consider the  following additional limitations:  •  All drives in the
>   array must be moved at the same time."

I want to move one hdd from each RAID 1 pair. to have mirrors untouched just in case.
Do they mean to move all 4 simultaniously?

> Smart Array 6i User Guide: Moving Drives and Arrays
>
> You can move drives to other ID positionson the same array controller.
>   You can  also move a complete arrayfrom one controller to another,
>   even if the controllers  are on different servers.
>
> Before you move drives, the following conditions must be met:
>   • If moving thedrives to a different server, the new server must have
>   enough  empty bays to accommodate all the drives simultaneously. 
>   • The move will not result in more than 14 physical drives per
>   controller  channel.
>   • No controller will be configured with more
>   than 32 logical volumes.
>   • The array has no failed or missing
>   drives.
>   • The array is in its original configuration.
>   • The controller is not reading from or writing to any of the spare drives
>   in the  array.
>   • The controller is not running capacity expansion,
>   capacity extension, or  RAID or stripe size migration.
>   • The controller is using the latestfirmware version (recommended).
>
> If you want to move an array to another controller, you must also
>   consider the  following additional limitations:
>   •  All drives in the array must be moved at the same time.
>   •  In most cases, a moved array
>   (and the logical drives that it contains) can still  undergo
>   arraycapacity expansion, logical drive capacity extension, or 
>   migration of RAID level orstripe size.
>
> When all the conditions have been met:
>
> 1. Back up all data before removing any drives or changing configuration. This  step is requiredif you are moving data-containing
>      drives from a controller  that does not have a battery-backed cache.
> 2. Power down the system.
> 3. If you are moving an array from a controller that contains a RAID ADG  logical volume to a controller that does not support RAID ADG:
> 4. Move the drives.
> 5. Power up the system. If a 1724 POST message is displayed, drive positions  were changed successfully and the configuration was
>      updated.  If a 1785 (NotConfigured)POST message is displayed:  a. 
>      Power down the system immediately to prevent data loss.  b.  Return
>      the drives to their original locations.  c.  Restore the data from
>      backup, if necessary.
> 6. Check the new drive configuration byrunning ORCA or ACU ("Configuring  an Array" on page 9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array configuration in Smart Array RAID controllers is stored on the disks, not the controller. Are you moving to an identical HP ProLiant DL380 G4?

If so, please place the drives in the same spots as they appear on the failed server... E.g. if there's a drive in bay #0 on the old server, place it in bay #0 of the new server. If there's a drive in bay #1 of the old server, place it in bay #1 of the new server... Repeat until done.

On the new system, power on... Pay very close attention to the BIOS messages. You are looking for the 1724 POST code during the array configuration BIOS screen.

`1724-Slot X Drive Array - Physical Drive Position Change(s) Detected`

That's all you should need to do.

Comment: second variant may also works , thus is bit dangerous, I tested with raid 0, eject both hdds, deleted logical volume, than insert to another working same server, they become unassigned there. Created raid 0 from them. All data appeared untouched on new raid 0 logical volume.

Comment: Make sure firmware on 6i is not 2.80. Ensure upgraded to 2.84